# I/O cost about Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When processing the same query repeatedly, can i assume that there is almost no I/O cost except the first query, since memory maybe holds the data that the following queries need. Assume that the query fits the memory.

Answer (score 0):

If the page cache is sized reasonably well that assumption should be true. Note that the graph is cached, but not the query results. So every time you run the query the graph is traversed (but nodes/rels/properties are hopefully picked from page cache and not from ssd/hdd).